# How to Change base url of subclassed AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In my application I am using AFNetworking for RESTful services. As adviced in the tutorial I subclassed the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` as a singleton class.

below is my implementation file

```
@implementation SENetworkOperationmanager
+ (SENetworkOperationmanager *)sharedSENetworkOperationmanagerWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    static SENetworkOperationmanager *_sharedWeatherHTTPClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedhttpOperationClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    });

    return _sharedhttpOperationClient;

}
- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if (self) {
        self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But my problem is that I have to change the base url when it need(We make our client type the given base url)

Help me that if there is a solution for changing the base url.